# How to deploy Angular to Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am deploying my Angular app to Firebase, but I can't get it to work. It is deployed, but shows the firebase default index.html that is generated while initializing firebase. How to make it show my app?

My firebase.json looks like this:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "dist/staff-manager",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The older version may have been cached. Can you try from other device or if possible share the URL?

Comment: I use incognito to open the url, still does not work. It is definitely something with the index.html. So when I run ng build I am not generating index.html, then when I run firebase init it is making a index.html in the folder selected, then I deploy. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out. When I run ng build I exceed the angular budgets configuration set in angular.json and therefor there is no index.html generated. Changing the budget to higher number fixed this issue and then when running firebase deploy everything works fine.